# Open file in Eclipse for PHP Developers

Tags: eclipse

Is is possible to open a file by right-click -> open with -> Eclipse? When I try it it open Eclipse asks for workspace, when I select the existing workspace it starts Eclipse, but does not open the file. And if the workspace is already open, it says workspace in use...

Is there a way to overcome this problem, I want to make eclipse the default editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default workspace in your Eclipse config.ini. I think that should make it work.

Here's a link on how to do that.

[Eclipse Zone](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t78109.rhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow has a pretty [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062694/eclipse-3-3-default-editor-under-vista) about setting Eclispe as the default PHP editor on Vista.